# Windows phone layer

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

How can I create the effect similar to Windows Phone's MessageBox, where the message gets displayed on a new layer with transparent background, so that the windows becomes modal? My layout is created out of Grid, so I do not know how to add any content over it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to overlay one set of content with another in WPF.  Try changing the visibility of the border below, for a simple message box effect.  You would of course bind Visibility to your view model, or set it in code behind.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <!-- All your layout here -->
    </Grid>
    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Background="Azure" Visibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock Text="Hi there" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it correct to place content inside Grid which is not in any of its rows? Or it is a workaround that "somehow works"?

Comment: The border is implicitly in row=0 column=0, and so is the nested grid. The nested grid fills the whole of the parent grid by default (default HorizontalAlignment=Stretch, VerticalAlignment=Stretch), and so does the border except that I restricted the height and width. It's legal to have multiple overlapping elements.  The elements z-order depends on the order they're added, so in this case border is on top of grid.